# Display default image in imageview if no image returned from server

Tags: android

**Goal**

Display a default image when no image is downloaded from server.

**Problem**

I have a listview with an imageview(along with a few textbox but thats not important). 
My imageview downloads images for students but when the student has no image I am trying to display a default image. 
I have tried two things I thought should work, set a default image, or the code below.
This code is taken from an activity file where I write the values from the database columns to variables (only showed img to maintain simplicity)

```
                   //Image path returned
                    if (javaRealObject.getString("img").equals(""))
                    {
                        imgv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
                        imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.emptyhead);

                        Log.d("Test", "Empty");
                    }
                    else//No image found in column
                    {
                        student.setImage(javaRealObject.getString("img"));
                        Log.d("Test","Not Empty");
                    }
```

However I am getting a null refernce on `imgv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);` and I am not sure why since my image view is being declared. 
Any help ti acheive the effect of a default image when none is 
supplied from the column will be appreciated.

For a bit more context, the code above is an activity that calls the listview.xml, which then calls the row.xml. the imageview in question is in row.xml file.

**ROW.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_head" /> //default image here

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFirstName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

List that calls row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
public class DriverAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Drivers> {

    ArrayList<Drivers> ArrayListDrivers;
    int Resource;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater vi;

    public DriverAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Drivers> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        ArrayListDrivers = objects;
        Resource = resource;
        this.context = context;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
            holder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
            holder.tvClientid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvid);
            holder.tvExpires = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_expdate);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(ArrayListDrivers.get(position).getImage());


        Glide.with(holder.imageview.getContext())
                .load(new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(ArrayListDrivers.get(position).getImage())        )
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.imageview);


        holder.tvName.setText(ArrayListDrivers.get(position).getFirstname());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(ArrayListDrivers.get(position).getLastname());
        holder.tvClientid.setText(ArrayListDrivers.get(position).getClient_id());
        holder.tvExpires.setText("Expiry Date:"+ArrayListDrivers.get(position).getExpires());



        return convertView;


    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvDescription;
        public TextView tvClientid;
        public TextView tvExpires;

    }


    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap cImg1 = null;


            try {

                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(urldisplay, Base64.DEFAULT);
                cImg1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return cImg1;


        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your XML code.

Comment: is  above code from your adapter class..?

Comment: Post the xml and log. One more thing you have to declare the findViewbyId line above if else condition.

Comment: @Tanimreja It is not the adapter class, it is part of the code inside a doinbackground method that assigns the strings from values taken from columns in the database.

Comment: Oh you have initialized the **imageView** inside of **Async** thats why its giving you **NullPointer**. Initialize **ImageView** outside of **Async**.

Comment: @Clairvoyant I'd actualyl done it outside, I only moved it inside because I was getting said error.

Answer (score 23):

There is a better way to do that, you can use one of the image loading libs like:

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

> An image loading and caching library for Android focused on smooth scrolling

and it will take you just one line to do what you want.

```
    Glide.with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

it's easier and cleaner.

Comment: I would actually like to use that but i have a question. I have edited the question and added my adapter. could you let on further instructions on implementing Glide there?

Comment: I get an error that the method placeholder cannot be resolved. Do you have any ideas why this is? The Glide library has, of course, been added to the project.

Comment: you can ask a new question with the code and I can help you.
but it's likely you have a typo in the placeholder name

Comment: I used the same with Picasso

Comment: @humazed can we use xml drawable as placeholder?

Answer (score 2):

Your Listview's adapter is responsible for managing your rows' views.
What is your adapter looks like? (the object that you call listview.setAdapter(Adapter) on).

Inside your adapter, there is a method call getView that you need to override and return a view object. You need to call view.findviewbyId() on this view object, not on your activity

**UPDATE**
Try remove these lines

```
holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(ArrayListDrivers.get(position).getImage());
```

P/s can you explain the purpose of calling Glide.with(Context).load(object)? thank you

Comment: Please look at my adapter code. I set the image resource in there

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by doing something very simple. 
In post exeucte of the aync method I simply said.

```
  if (result != null){
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
```

That way if it is null, the default imageview will not be over written with "null"
. 
Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 2):

Add  gradle dependency:

```
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
   implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.0'
```

In order to use it:

```
  Glide.with(mActivity.getApplicationContext())
                            .load(EndPoints.ROWS_IMAGE_URL + ImageUrl)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .centerCrop()
                            .transform(new CropCircleTransformation(mActivity.getApplicationContext()))
                            .apply(new RequestOptions().
                            .placeholder(drawable)
                            .error(drawable)
                            .override(AppConstants.ROWS_IMAGE_SIZE, AppConstants.ROWS_IMAGE_SIZE))
                            .into(target);
```

The following line of code causes a default image to be displayed in the event of an error:

```
   .placeholder(drawable)
```

Answer (score 1):

This method would work - 
Set a default image in your xml code, which will be displayed when student has no image.
Dynamically set image using setImageResource(...) if you got an image.

Recheck the id of your ImageView as you are getting null reference error and if this does not solve the problem then please post the complete activity code.

Comment: Yes you will get null reference error as your activity has no idea about your row.xml you can only call views in the xml containing listview.

You can access that imageview onlye where you are setting that row in the listview like in adapter class

Comment: I am doing exactly that in my adapter (i pasted it above) however default images are not showed. I believe it is because it assigns it "nothnig" as it gets nothing from the image path in the query.

Answer (score 1):

In your `AsyncTask constructor` try to initialize your Image view like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, false);
ivImage= (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
```

here `row.xml` where you declare ImageView ... and make sure ivImage is global variable... now ivImage is not null. i checked it.. but its better to use `adapter` class for managing  a `listview row....`

Comment: I tried inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); ( in the onCreate) and View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, false); ivImage= (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage); imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_head); in the Aync method but still no default image